# How to make Leaderboard slider banner responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, banner

I tried very hard to make this leaderboard slider banner but could not succeed.
This is the [Banner Test Page](https://freeairdrop.io/airdrop/bannertest.html) ( The Second Sliding Banner ).

When I use without this slider my Webpage is fully responsive. You can check here my [Original Page](https://freeairdrop.io/airdrop/banano.html)

Please help me in makeing my Banner Test Page Responsive.

Thanks for the help.

```
.sliderWrapper
{
box-shadow: 0 0 40px 10px #000;
height: 90px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 728px;
}
.sliderWrapper .slider
{
background: #aaa;
overflow: hidden;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}
.sliderWrapper .slider .slide
{
display: none;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
}
.sliderWrapper .slider .slide img { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.sliderWrapper .slider-directions .slider-directions-prev,
.sliderWrapper .slider-directions .slider-directions-next
{
cursor: pointer;
background: #eee;
color: #333;
height: 48px;
position: absolute;
top: 35%;
width: 24px;
z-index: 10;
box-shadow: 0;
transition-property: left,right,box-shadow;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
transition-timing-function: ease;
}
.sliderWrapper .slider-directions .slider-directions-prev:after,
.sliderWrapper .slider-directions .slider-directions-next:after
{
content: 'O';
display: block;
line-height: 48px;
}
.sliderWrapper .slider-directions .slider-directions-prev { left: -24px; }
.sliderWrapper:hover .slider-directions .slider-directions-prev { left: 0; box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.8); }
.sliderWrapper .slider-directions .slider-directions-prev:after { content: '«'; }
.sliderWrapper .slider-directions .slider-directions-next { right: -24px; }
.sliderWrapper:hover .slider-directions .slider-directions-next { right: 0; box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.8); }
.sliderWrapper .slider-directions .slider-directions-next:after { content: '»'; }
.sliderWrapper .slider-navigation
{
bottom: -24px;
color: #333;
left: 2px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
transition-property: bottom;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
transition-timing-function: ease;
}
.sliderWrapper:hover .slider-navigation { bottom: 2px; }
.sliderWrapper .slider-navigation .slider-navigation-item
{
cursor: pointer;
background: #eee;
border-radius: 100%;
box-shadow: 0;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
height: 12px;
margin-left: 2px;
margin-right: 2px;
text-indent: -9999px;
width: 12px;
transition-property: box-shadow;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
transition-timing-function: ease;
}
.sliderWrapper:hover .slider-navigation .slider-navigation-item {
box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.sliderWrapper .slider-navigation .slider-navigation-item.active {
background: #333;
color: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create al your banners inside slider as same height-width / resolution first

Then you can give `max-width:100%;` and `height:90px` to your slider

That will make it as much responsive as the first banner in your site

Changes needed in your CSS

```
.sliderWrapper {
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px 10px #000;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 728px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Try these media queries for your height issue on small screen devices

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 325px) {
  .sliderWrapper {
    height:35px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 326px)  and (max-width: 375px) {
  .sliderWrapper {
    height:45px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 376px) and (max-width: 425px) {
  .sliderWrapper {
    height:50px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 426px) and (max-width: 540px) {
  .sliderWrapper {
    height:65px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 540px) {
  .sliderWrapper {
    height:90px;
  }
}
```

Just keep in mind that you'd have to make all banner of same height-width for the best result of images in banners

For the latest edit, make this changes

```
.sliderWrapper .slider .slide img{
width:100%;
height:auto;
position:absolute:
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
margin:auto;
}

.sliderWrapper .slider{
background:#f9f9f9;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206629/discussion-on-answer-by-sarfraaz-talat-how-to-make-leaderboard-slider-banner-res).